# how to scale artwork and content from mm to pixels

Tags: adobe-illustrator, css, html, mockup

i'm making a template of a ticket of 80mm for a web app in Illustrator CC 2017, but now realize that when i go to export>save for web, the size of the artwork and content change to pixels, but not transform 80mm to the actual size in pixels instead the program just changed 80mm to 227px which is the same size on the inside ruler of illustrator.

Why is this happening can someone help?

How can i scale the artwork and his content from milimeters to the real size in pixels for print from web.

Comment: You can not a pixel has no size, its a sample and that is infinitely small. However you can define a conversion factor which by convention (magic) is 72 pixels per inch. However it will never have a physical size of 80 mm on any device in existence. It will in fact be different on every different device and user zoom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is..

80mm = 227px at 72 Pixel/Inch (the resolution at which Illustrator's **Save for Web**, saves) so I'm not sure where the problem is.

**From Adobe Help Center:**

"*[When you save artwork in a bitmap format, such as JPEG, GIF, or PNG, Illustrator rasterizes the artwork at 72 pixels per inch.](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/best-practices-creating-web-graphics.html)*"

> If you wish to save directly from AI at a different resolution, use
>   **Export** instead of **Save for Web**, It allows you to choose between 72ppi, 150ppi, 300ppi or Other (this will allow you to add
>   your own):

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

You mentioned in the comments but "*really 80mm are 302.362204728px*" and that is right and wrong at the same time. I have mentioned in my answer that save for web saves at a resolution of 72 Pixel/Inch. That means 80mm will have a value of  227px when exported.

[image]

Your resulted value comes from a 96 Pixel/Inch resolution that translates to roughly 302px.

[image]

You can open your exported image in Photoshop, go to Image>Image Size and you will see the resolution of your AI exported image has a resolution of 72.

---

Check out this calculator:

http://www.pixelcalculator.com/?round=&FORM=1&DP=1&FA=&lang=en&mm1=80&mm2=&dpi1=72&sub1=+calculate+#a1

It will help you understand better.

---

Also, for more on the topic, check out this answer form @joojaa :

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/100684/48529

Comment: Right now 80mm change to 227px when i try to save for web, but really 80mm are 302.362204728px [https://engineeringunits.com/mm-to-pixels/](https://engineeringunits.com/mm-to-pixels/) so when i see the document in the browser and try to print it is not 80mm anymore.

Comment: @ioannis that is where you are right and wrong at the same time. I have already mentioned that save for web saves at 72 pixel/inch. The value at which you made that calculation is for 96 Pixel/inch. I will make an update to my answer.

Comment: Thanks now i understand much better, so now i need to know how change the pixel/inch property in illustrator to 96. (EDIT) now i see you showed in the answer thankss!!!